# read_excel vs read_csv: object-dtype column behaviour

Tags: python, pandas

I have a table, and one of the columns look like below:

```
COLUMN
string_value
string_value
string_value
0
0
0
string_value
...
```

**read_csv**

```
df = pd.read_csv('file.csv')
```

`df.COLUMN.isin(['0']).any()`,-> TRUE.

**read_excel**

```
df = pd.read_excel('file.xslx')
```

`df.COLUMN.isin(['0']).any()` -> FALSE.

`df.COLUMN.isin([0]).any()` -> TRUE.

Why is this happening? Both columns get read as object dtype but the numbers get parsed as string in read_csv and as number in read_excel.

Comment: `excel` can store different dtypes in a column. I can have one row with `0` followed by another row with `'0'`. `pandas` preserves these types upon reading, and the `object` dtype is perfectly happy holding any number of different dtypes. With a csv there is no such thing as datatypes. So when you specify `object` everything becomes a string exactly as it appears in the csv.

Comment: For the above example, for big datasets, I discovered that read_csv() also may show the behaviour: 
``` df.COLUMN.isin([0]).any()``` -> TRUE. We can avoid this by doing read_csv(file.csv, low_memory = False). In this way, all numbers present in an object column (if any) will be preperly read only as string, and not as a mixture of string and number (i.e. both '0' and 0). This may cause bugs if not aware.